# Which mount is this Sigma lens for?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, sigma

I have lens that does not fit my Nikon or Canon. 
Can someone tell me what camera this lens is for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did some more research and it seems to be a Konica? not sure though.

Comment: I tried it on a Canon Xsi and it did not fit

Answer (score 9):

I think you've got a [Minolta A-mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minolta_A-mount_system) lens. Compare to this photo (image borrowed [from here](http://cameragx.com/2009/10/10/50-years-of-lens-mount-evolution-part-v-of-vi/minolta-a-mount-0172/)):

[image: Minolta A-mount]

Minolta and Konica merged at some point and were subsequently acquired by Sony, and this mount is apparently still used by Sony as the "Alpha mount system".

Answer (score -2):

It is a Minolta mount! Have a Look at the rear cap of this lens. (If you still have) There you should see "For ..."

Comment: Which one?  A-mount, SR-mount?

Answer (score -3):

Naaa

This is the Sigma SA mount.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_SA-mount

which is like a cross between the pentax K mount (mechanically) and the canon mount (electronically)

Comment: The Sigma SA mount has [a significantly different number of contracts](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JjUPS.jpg) than shown in the OP's image.