# What is the mount on this Sigma lens? It is smaller than Canon EF

Tags: lens, lens-mount, sigma

I just got a SIGMA 17-70 1:2:8-4 DC (C) lense. Mount looks very much like Canon EF (S) but it's smaller. Added a foto from a 70-200 EF to compare. Anybody knows what this mount is for? Many thanks in advance

[image: Sigma measure]

[image: Canon measure]

[image: Sigma Objectiv Image1]

[image: Sigma mount Image1]

Comment: could it be a sigma SA mount?

Comment: [EF-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-M_lens_mount) perhaps?  Its 47mm throat diameter looks similar to your measurement

Comment: that's what I thought first but SIgma says on there webpage it would be only available for: Canon EF-Mount, Nikon F-Mount, SIGMA SA-Mount, Pentax K-Mount, Sony A-Mount

Comment: SA seems likely then.  Take a look at the linked picture from the comment on this answer; does that look like what you've got?: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65303/which-mount-is-this-sigma-lens-for/65308

Comment: It's a little odd since it looks like most Sigma SA mount lenses have only 5 contacts in the larger group, but it looks like maybe some of them have more?

Comment: This looks like the same thing, so yes, SA: https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/sigma-17-70mm-2-4-macro-dc-sigma-sa-1791976047

Comment: perfect, thanks. THink that's it. Found some ebay auctions for SA lenses with the same type of mount (the one with more then 5 contacts. I guess the mystery is solved :-). Many thanks for your responses!!

Comment: @NateS. This discussion in comments is a good example of the site's guideline: [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short)

Comment: @scottbb, I was going to after OP confirmed that it was indeed the same thing, since I couldn't quite tell at first, but they beat me to it.  It's preserved in an answer, and I'm not too worried about the points, so I'm not sure there's much value in me writing the same thing in an answer of my own now, but I can if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Nate S. for his answer.

> This looks like the same thing, so yes, SA:
>   https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/sigma-17-70mm-2-4-macro-dc-sigma-sa-1791976047

Solution is Sigma SA Mount

Comment: Sigma SA reportedly uses the same communication protocol as Canon EF, which explains why it looks like an EF mount from an alternate universe.

Comment: IIRC you have have the mount changed by Sigma service. Nice lens, that's my "standard" one. Just a bit soft at 17mm.